# How to create middleware API in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, webhooks, middleware, asp.net-core-middleware

I need to write a middleware micro service API from another website which is SSL secured; I need to load the certificate and wait for any post calls on that url and catch the data in my end. I have the certificate but they are `.cer` and `.pk` files. Any ideas how to make this?

I've tried mapPost that only references on my local project.

Comment: _"make middleware microservice api from another website"_ This sounds like you are proxying requests to another service. If so, this isn't really appropriate for ASP.NET Core middleware which is intended to modify or intercept requests as part of the request pipeline.

Comment: Well they requested that they don't want to call our microservice and we sent them multiple emails that they need to implement our post method to actually work. I have no more ideas this is my last chance.

Comment: They requested that they don't want to call your API/micro service but it sounds like you're trying to write code for _their_ website that would do this instead. I'm a little confused about what you're hoping to achieve.

Comment: Well, yes, I am. That is what confuses all of us because they provided certificates to establish the connection between the two applications. After three emails of saying they need to implement a POST method to call our side, they didn't. So, I guess they want a microservice API to listen for POST calls if it is possible.

Comment: If they are providing certificates then it sounds like they are expecting your service to call their website 

Comment: It turns out my team wanted to make this change to listen for POST calls. I have the link, which I assume is a query that retrieves the models added from a certain date to today. So that means I only need to call the URL and get the data. Thank you for your time.